# How to create button IBAction from page view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a walkthrough/onboarding process when a user first uses the app. I am doing this with a Page View Controller. On the last screen I have a button which I just dragged to a tab bar view controller to create a segue. But I actually need an IBaction now for the button tap. I have tried CTRL dragging the button everywhere but the only option I get is is "Exit" instead of an action. How can I create an IBaction for this button?

Here is the page view controller code

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {



    var pageControl = UIPageControl()

    // MARK: UIPageViewControllerDataSource

    lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.newVc(viewController: "sbBlue"),
                self.newVc(viewController: "sbRed"),
                self.newVc(viewController: "sbGreen")]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self



        // This sets up the first view that will show up on our page control
        if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
            setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                               direction: .forward,
                               animated: true,
                               completion: nil)
        }

        configurePageControl()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func configurePageControl() {
        // The total number of pages that are available is based on how many available colors we have.
        pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 50,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = orderedViewControllers.count
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
        self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.addSubview(pageControl)



    }

    func newVc(viewController: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewController)
    }


    // MARK: Delegate methords
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0]
        self.pageControl.currentPage = orderedViewControllers.index(of: pageContentViewController)!
    }

    // MARK: Data source functions.
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

        // User is on the first view controller and swiped left to loop to
        // the last view controller.
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            //return orderedViewControllers.last
            // Uncommment the line below, remove the line above if you don't want the page control to loop.
            return nil
        }

        guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
        let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count

        // User is on the last view controller and swiped right to loop to
        // the first view controller.
        guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
            //return orderedViewControllers.first
            // Uncommment the line below, remove the line above if you don't want the page control to loop.
            return nil
        }

        guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]


    }
}
```

Comment: *"I have a button which I just dragged to a tab bar view controller"* ... Do you mean your last VC shown in the page view controller is a `UITabBarController`? So at that point the user can switch tabs, while still in the pages?

Comment: @DonMag, the entry point is a page view controller which has 3 walkthrough screens. On the 3rd screen I have a button. I CTRL dragged that button to a tab view controller which is basically the home screen. This is just a segue. If it isn't the first time the app has been opened it should default to the tab view controller. I need the button tap IBaction on the 3rd walktrhough screen to create a user default so the app knows not to show the walkthrough screens again

Comment: You can either create / attach an IBAction in the 3rd walkthrough screen (its view controller), or, what is probably a better option, implement `prepareForSegue` in the 3rd VC and set your user default value there.

Comment: @DonMag, that's the problem. If I link the 3rd VC to the page view controller class, the 3rd VC never appears, it only cycles through the first 2. So, I can't do that and therefore I can't implement prepareForSegue either?

Comment: The default class for the 3 VC's is UIViewController

Comment: If you don't want to create a simple subclass for that 3rd VC, you could set your user defaults value in `viewDidLoad()` in your tabBarController's first tab VC. It would get set every time (because after the first run, your AppDelegate I'm assuming is checking for that user defaults value and "launching" the tabBarController instead of the page view controller), but that wouldn't affect anything.

Comment: Good idea. What I actually ended up doing was setting the user defaults in the 3rd vc where the button is. It is the last screen in the onboarding so it's pretty much exactly the same as if they pressed the button.

Comment: I would upvote your comment but can't because I don't have enough points or something. You can add it as your answer though and hopefully I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you just want to set a value in user defaults showing that the user has "seen the 3rd screen" you could:

- set the value in `viewDidLoad()` of the 3rd VC
- set the value in `prepareForSegue in the 3rd VC
- set the value in `viewDidLoad()` of the 1st tab's VC of the tabViewController

From your comments, looks like you settled on option "A"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the page view controller in the storyboard is connected to the corresponding controller file.

[image]

Comment: thanks for that. But after doing that I never reach the 3rd screen with the button. It just cycles through the first 2 and loops those, never reaching the 3rd?